# Differentiating two views with same controller for different user in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I have two different views of each page in an application.                          One view is the editable view where a user can come and edit stuff.This view has Buttons, Text Input, Text Area etc. The other view is used to just view the data. The buttons should be hidden, Text Input, Text Area which were editable should be replaced with label.

So I have a doubt whether I should have:

**(i) two different html files for each view which can be changed inside the router

(ii)same html file and use ng-if

(iii)same html file and create directive for each change**

Comment: same html file and use ng-if

Comment: @SourabhAgrawal if I do so, I have to do it in all the place, instead i can create a directive once and replace everywhere

Comment: I didnt considered that use case . but yeah its thats what you have go with directives .

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many `ng-if` directives you have to create. In other words how large your view is.

If it is a small view - go for `ng-if`.

If not, use a separate template for the view.

Comment: What if I there is combination of the both editable and view mode inside one feature in future?